# org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name XXX defined in class path resource

Tags: java, spring

I am not writing setter getter and using autowire instead then getting following error-

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'aS400Statusfacade' defined in class path resource [CXF-Bean.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'aS400StatusDAO' of bean class [com.metlife.mymet.admin.facade.AS400Statusfacade]: Bean property 'aS400StatusDAO' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1279)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1010)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:472)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:250)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:429)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:728)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:380)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
```

My **Spring-conf.xml**

```
<bean id="aS400Statusfacade"
    class="com.metlife.mymet.admin.facade.AS400Statusfacade">
    <property name="aS400StatusDAO" ref="aS400StatusDAO"></property>
</bean>
```

My class with autowire-

```
public class AS400Statusfacade {
    Logger logger=Logger.getLogger(AS400Statusfacade.class);
    @Autowired
    AS400StatusDAO aS400StatusDAO=null;

    public String getAS400StatusInformation() {
        return aS400StatusDAO.getAS400Status();
    }
}
```

Comment: why are you mixing bean dependency injection via both xml configuration and annotation?

Comment: thanks for the comment but Its a very well scenario we do autowiring on property we are setting in bean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem you are running into is that without the setter and an explicit  tag Spring doesn't know what you want from it.

Try removing the explicit property element.

This will allow for the @Autowired annotation to attempt resolution of the value.

To illustrate this further:

spring-conf.xml

```
<bean id="aS400Statusfacade"
    class="com.metlife.mymet.admin.facade.AS400Statusfacade">
    <!--
        The following property tag is not necessary. Spring's
        @Autowired and associated bean post-processor, will introspect
        and set the property with an appropriate candidate bean.
        Bean property setter, is not required for the post-processor
        to access/set the property.
    -->
    <!--
    <property name="aS400StatusDAO" ref="aS400StatusDAO"></property>
    -->
</bean>
```

AS400Statusfacade illustration

```
public class AS400Statusfacade {
    Logger logger=Logger.getLogger(AS400Statusfacade.class);
    @Autowired
    AS400StatusDAO aS400StatusDAO=null;

    public String getAS400StatusInformation() {
        return aS400StatusDAO.getAS400Status();
    }
}
```

Comment: I haven't understood,can u please explain what do u mean by explicit property.

Comment: @Rahulray When you use `@Autowired` it does map the setters for you. You don't need to configure another `<property>` that will do the same thing. Don't explicitly configure property in XML configuration when you already say to container that it's only being `Autowired`